# What to do with posts asking 10+ questions w/ bounty?

Tags: discussion

So this question came up today: [Understanding code and pratical](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112913/understanding-code-and-pratical)

There's like 15 broad questions in one single post, this question to me is way too broad but the bounty protects it.

Anything we can do ?

Comment: Wait till the bounty is over then destroy it.

Comment: @Marius was expecting a more subtile way ^^ alright thanks for that

Comment: Sorry for the not so subtile answer. I am on vacation and I try to answer as short as possible.

Comment: @Marius after your vacation, then please consider to post ^^^ as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally a bounty should not allow a user to post bad questions. But it kind of does. You can only add a bounty 48h after posting the question. If nobody spottet the bad question during that time it means it is a legit question.
However, whenn the bounty expires, you can vote to close it.